# Is it possible to escape a space in a word list sigil?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to create an atom list with all the provinces of Argentina. Since some of the are composed of multiple words, I need to escape the whitespace.

```
~w[
  Buenos\sAires
  Capital\sfederal Catamarca Chaco Chubut Corrientes Córdoba
  Entre\sRíos Formosa Jujuy La\sPampa La\sRioja Mendoza Misiones Neuquén
  Río\sNegro Salta San\sJuan San\ Luis Santa\sCruz Santa\sFe
  Santiago\sdel\sEstero Tierra\sdel\sFuego Tucumán
]a
```

I've tried using `sigil_w` and `sigil_W`, with the classic escaping sequences `\` and `\s`, but it does not work.

> (26 provinces - 1) * (2 quotes (") + 1 comma (,) + 1 space for readability(" ")) - 25 spaces I would use with the sigil form = 75 characters I could save

I know I can achieve this using a custom sigil:

```
defmodule MySigil do
  def sigil_X(string, [])  do
   string
   |> String.split(~r/\s/)
   |> Enum.map(&String.replace(&1, "\\s", " "))
  end
end

import MySigil
~X[Buenos\sAires La\sPlata]
["Buenos Aires", "La Plata"]
```

... but is there less "homemade" approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `sigil_w` and `sigil_W` both [call the private `split_words`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/882c2bdb24ea1539dc0639116692378e18dbc4ac/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L5008) method in the `Kernel` module, [which uses `String.split`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/882c2bdb24ea1539dc0639116692378e18dbc4ac/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L5048-L5057) to split the string which will always split on any whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

While it’s not possible without hacks, there is a kludge around. Copy-paste the code below into your `iex` and execute it:

```
~w|a b c|
#⇒ ["a b", "c"]
```

[**NB** unfortunately, SO has the original symbol converted to normal space, hence copy-paste won’t work out of the box]
*I can hear your “wut?” :)*

This is achieved with a [non-breakable space](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/). If you are fine with this, just use nbsp and you are all set.

Comment: Also `~w[a\u00a0b c]`.

Comment: @Dogbert which is essentially the same :)

Comment: Yep, probably better than sneaking in a non-breaking space into the source code though.

Comment: Your example does not work, using elixir 1.5.2. I would rather spare the head scratching to my poor coworkers though :p. @Dogbert's does work, but having to type 6 characters defeats the purpose of the sigil.

Comment: Looks like StackOverflow converted the non-breaking space to a normal space. It doesn't work for me either if I copy paste the snippet.

Comment: @Dogbert Nah, indeed. When I have checked it I probably had my original in the keyboard buffer. Anyway, you got the point. I have a custom keyboard layout hence I just typed AltGr+Space for it.